# How to define piece-wise functions in Z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

I would like to define a piece-wise (linear) function in Z3py, for example, the function `f(x)` has the form

```
f(x) = a*x + b when 0 <= x <= 1
f(x) = exp(c*x) when 1 < x <= 2
f(x) = 1/(1+10^x) when 2 < x <= 3
etc.
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are constants.

I guess the `z3.If()` function will be relevant, but as the number of pieces grows, the expression gets convoluted.

My questions is, does Z3pyprovides the if-else statement, or is there an elegant way to define piece-wise function in Z3py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Z3 supports if-then-elses and in Python they can be constructed using the `If` function. An example from the documentation of `If`:

```
>>> x = Int('x')
>>> y = Int('y')
>>> max = If(x > y, x, y)
max = If(x > y, x, y)
```